# Search for keywords in osascript output

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a small script to print what terminal said script is being run in.

```
osascript -e 'POSIX path of (path to frontmost application)'
```

so far this would print something like

```
/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/
```

I want to do something like search the string for a list of key words e.g "Terminal.app" "iTerm.app" ect.
or do something like exclude "/", "Applications" and "Utilities" to filter it out.

all the methods of searching strings i found seem to need it in a variable and i couldn't figure out how to pipe it into a variable.

Comment: And yes, to answer your question about variable — `VAR=$(osa....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a file path, might as well use a file utility - [basename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

```
osascript -e 'POSIX path of (path to frontmost application)' | xargs basename
```

Comment: Also the possibility. The advantage of embedding into `$()` is that you can specify second argument to `basename`. What I meant to be `.app/` in my comment to @niculare's answer, but somehow are ate the `.app` part. It is certainly possible with xargs, but at the expense of beauty ;-)

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.
And thanks @Michael Krelin - hacker, your method works great too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
osascript -e 'POSIX path of (path to frontmost application)' | cut -d"/" -f4
```

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker even better and simpler than my solution;)

Comment: Fails for any path that's not exactly three tiers deep.